# Disable suggestions by chrome in address field

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome

How can I disable suggestions to address input in Google Chrome, from code, not Chrome preferences. The others fields are OK with autocomplete="false" instruction. I attached an image. Thanks you
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbOef.png)

Comment: same problem here. Can it really be true, that chrome cannot be kept from doing this?? Its year 2019!

Answer (score 0):

It seems imlpossoble nowadays to disable autocomplete.
BUT MDN offers to use disable autocomplete plugin: "This plugin will randomize input name attribute by default. It will restore back to original field name when submitting form. This is for preventing auto completion for all browsers (includes third-party auto-completeion extensions) not just for Google Chrome.".

http://www.terrylinooo.github.io/jquery.disableAutoFill

Hope that helps